# Hashing the password if it is not hashed in django

Tags: django, hash, passwords

When I try to create a password for the user using the admin interface is doesn't get hashed.
So I added this line in the user model

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_password(self.password)
```

While this solves the issue.
while creating user using `createsuperuser` it saves the password as a hash But when I try to login into the admin interface is says incorrect password.
I'm sure it's caused by the adding the above line into the code.
When i remove the line, createsuperuser works fine but password isn't hashed in the admin interface, when i add the line admin works while createsuperuser doesn't.
I want to hash the password if it isn't hashed yet.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    role = models.ForeignKey(to=Role, to_field='role', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, editable=True, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)], null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/', blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    complaint = GenericRelation(Complaint)
    # Specify unique related names for the groups and user_permissions fields
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ),
        related_name='custom_users',  # Change the related name to 'custom_users'
    )

    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        verbose_name=_('user permissions'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('Specific permissions for this user.'),
        related_name='custom_users',  # Change the related name to 'custom_users'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.username}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.role_id == 'admin':
            self.is_staff = True

        if self.image:
            img = Image.open(self.image.path)

            if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
                output_size = (300, 300)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.image.path)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'password', 'image', 'role')
```

Comment: Did you create a custom user model, if yes, share the model and the admin. Don't set the password in the `save()`, this will hash the password a second and third, etc. time each time you save the user model again.

Comment: I just want the password to be hashed when A new user is created using the admin interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't hash in the `.save(…)` method: this will hash the password each time you save the model object again. Since `createsuperuser` already hashes the password, it would thus hash the password a second time, making it useless for the (first) password. It would require logging in with the hash of the first password.

The way Django's default admin for `User` works is by plugging in a form that hashes it. We can plug this in for the custom admin as well:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'role', 'image')


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'role', 'image')


@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'password', 'image', 'role')
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
```

This will also ensure that the password is shown as an `<input type="password'>` so hiding the password on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hash the password in the admin interface.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ##
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if the password is set and not already hashed
        if self.password and not self.password.startswith('pbkdf2_sha256$'):
            self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: IMO this is better handled in whatever form is being used to create / update the user. Also one drawback of this is that it (as implemented) doesn't handle the various possible password hashers that can be used with Django and also doesn't respect the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` setting.

Comment: There are two problems here: the first is that a different hasher can have been used, the second that some (probably technically minded) people could use `pbkdf2_sha256$` as the start of their password, and thus these would then not be able to log in later.